# Save entire movie file into PNG images using OpenGLES 2.0 in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es-2.0, objective-c-blocks

Below code is to save each frame of a movie to Photo Album in iPad device... It drops lot of frame while glReadPixel and saving to Photo Album.. what is the best approach for this requirement without dropping a single ..

From my observation, the most expensive thing happening here is while UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(..) - write to device..

Step 1: Read the frame and create the pixel buffer and frame buffer and pass it to saveImageToPhotoAlbum..

Step 2: Create UIImage from glReadPixel to create the buffer out of frame buffer

Step 3: Once there is a valid UIImage, then write to device..

```
-(void)playMovie 
{
  //
  // blah.. blah.. blah..
  // 
  // retrive PixelBuffer for each frame and the Frame Buffer and pass it to save the image
  //

  [self saveImageToPhotoAlbum : gluFrameBBuffer];
}

 -(UIImage *) getImageFromGLBuffer : GLuint frameBuffer : (CGCize) screenSize
{
    glBindFramebuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);

    int width = screenSize.width;
    int height = screenSize.height;

    NSInteger iDataLength =  width * height * 4;

    // allocate array and read pixels into it.
    GLubyte *buffer = (GLubyte *) malloc( iDataLength );
    glReadPixels(0,  0, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);

    glBindFramebuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

    // gl renders "upside down" so swap top to bottom into new array.
    // there's gotta be a better way, but this works.
    GLubyte *buffer2 = (GLubyte *) malloc(iDataLength);

    for(int y = 0; y <height; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < width * 4; x++)
        {
            buffer2[(int)((height - 1 - y) * width * 4 + x)] = buffer[(int)(y * 4 * width + x)];
        }
    }

    // Release the first buffer
    free((void*)buffer);

    // make data provider with data.
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, buffer2, iDataLength, releaseBufferData);

    // prep the ingredients
    int bitsPerComponent = 8;
    int bitsPerPixel = 32;
    int bytesPerRow = 4 * width;

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
    CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;

    // make the cgimage
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(width, height, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo, provider, NULL, NO, renderingIntent);

    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);

    // then make the UIImage from that
    UIImage *image =  [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]; //[[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imageRef];

    NSData* imageData =  UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);     // get png representation
    UIImage* pngImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    CGImageRelease(imageRef);

    return pngImage;
}

// callback for CGDataProviderCreateWithData
void releaseBufferData(void *info, const void *data, size_t dataSize)
{
    NSLog(@"releaseBufferData\n");
    // free the buffer
    free((void*)data);
}

- (void)saveImageToPhotoAlbum : GLuint frameBuffer : (CGCize) screenSize
{
    if( iqFrameBuffer != nil )
    {
        UIImage* image = [self getImageFromGLBuffer:frameBuffer : screenSize];

        if( image != nil)
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
            });
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Couldn't save to Photo Album due to invalid image..");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Frame buffer is invalid. Couldn't save to image..");
    }
}

// callback for UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum
- (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{
    NSLog(@"Image has been saved to Photo Album successfully..\n");
 //   [image release];   // release image
    image = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all...

```
UIImage *image =  [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]; //[[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imageRef];

NSData* imageData =  UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);     // get png representation
UIImage* pngImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

This code actuallly does nothing, pngImage is the same as image and wastes time and memory doing the conversions.

You have UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum on a seperate thread so it should not be the cause of dropping frames. Most likely the bottleneck is simply on glReadPixels, which is slow.

Comment: Thanks... Jack! I have already removed those lines.. still the same result.. you might be right... glReadPixel is the main culprit... no idea.. how to optimize that part though..

Comment: @codersnet Theres no going around the glReadpixels() bottleneck that I know of...there might be some crazy hacks that might speed this up, You might want to find a different way to save the video. Where are you getting the video from? a stream? local file? Try using the AVFramework instead of trying to read form the graphics memory

Comment: I have both requirements.. local video file as well as streaming.. what I am trying to do here is .. process a video using OpenGLES and either write the Frame Buffer to image files or display on the screen...